# Yocto PHP5 image Installation

Tags: php, linux, yocto

I has a project  which controls camera with pwm  while sending data from the Webserver .I'm using Yocto dizzy  branch for to generate sdcard image for Wandboard Quad . Kernel version is 3.10.17 .

I used php code to post the data to the test.py file so I need the php package for wandboard  to make it understandable for test.py file  then I will write  some python code to send  pwm depending on data's but in yocto I couldn't figure out how to add this functionality to the sdcard image. I worked  about 4 day about that but I couldn't   find any solution .Do you know how can I apply this functionality ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use such an old kernel and such an old Yocto distribution?

I have a 4.9.x kernel with pyro and php 7.1.0[1] which should also run on a Wandboard with the correct device tree.[2]

[1] https://github.com/RobertBerger/meta-mainline/tree/pyro-training-v4.9.x/multi-v7-ml/recipes-devtools/php

[2] https://github.com/RobertBerger/meta-mainline/blob/pyro-training-v4.9.x/multi-v7-ml/conf/machine/multi-v7-ml.conf#L126